# Propel autoescaping for display

Tags: mysql, escaping, propel

Does propel auto escape data pulled from the database for display or do I have to escape the output in my template?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with escaping the conversion of HTML-entities so safe output: no. Propel does not auto-escape data for you. That's the job of your template engine. (Twig for example does it per default)